# Crystal Report String parameter truncating string

Tags: .net, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-2010

We are exporting data to pdf through crystal reports, i have a string parameter lets say X and it's formula is:

```
WhilePrintingRecords;
shared stringvar Y;
Y
```

When we have a big string(more that 8000 characters) in Y it is truncating in PDF.
Y is the column which returns from stored proc.
can any one suggest what is going wrong.

Comment: Are you sure it is not the stored procedure that truncates the text? The max. length for StringVar in CR is 65534. Can you show the stored procedure?

Comment: Thanks @MatSnow for the reply, we changed the stored proc and did not update it in CR. Once we updated the database in report it started printing whole string.